# How do i only action at UserControl?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WP8.Progress"
    ..................................
    d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Rectangle Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.75" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ProgressBar Foreground="Blue" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I call UserControl in MainPage:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="WP8.MainPage"
    ..................................
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black">
        <Grid>
            <Button Name="btnButton" Content="OK" Click="btnButton_Click"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <uc:Progress />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

When i run app, i see UserControl upper MainPage but i still pressed button at MainPage.
How do i only action at UserControl?

Comment: The question isn't clear, what is your goal? How about simply setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the `<Grid>` where `btnButton` resides?

Comment: Thank for har07 answered my question. when usercontrol progress is running, i can click button at mainpage. i don't want to such...

Answer (score 0):

I got your question i have done the same thing in my App when you are opening the UserControl set your LayoutRoot.IsHitTestVisible="False" and after then the user has done on the usercontrol or usercontrol is closed then set it as true. And you can also do some opacity or visibility changes if you want with the grid.